# awk or grep? - print keyword and following columns

Tags: awk, grep, columns

I did some benchmarks and the output is a single file containing multiple results with the following format

```
[blaaa]
1st run

T/V   N  NB  P  Q   Time
==========================
2     3   4  1  2   1.02
[blaaaa...]
2nd run
T/V   N  NB  P  Q   Time
==========================
4     42 4  1  2    1.22
```

I want only to obtain the runtimes of the different runs I made. So is it possible to grep "Time" and print the next but one column? Or even to print out only

```
1.02
1.22
```

for my example above? I would prefer printing out only the three result columns without the blaa part :D

Comment: You mean the same column, next but one *line*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `Time` is always in the sixth field:

```
$ awk '$6 == "Time" {t = NR} t && NR == t+2 {print $6}' file
1.02
1.22
```

Alternatively you could use `getline` twice - quick'n'dirty:

```
awk '$6 == "Time" {getline; getline; print $6}' file
```

("dirty" because it doesn't check the `getline` return value).

Comment: Or use `$NF` if it's always the _last_ column.

Comment: @Kusalananda yes good point

Answer (score 0):

```
$ grep -o 'Time\|[0-9\.]\+$' file
Time
1.02
Time
1.22
$ grep -o '[0-9\.]\+$' file
1.02
1.22
$ grep -A2 ^T/V file
T/V   N  NB  P  Q   Time
==========================
2     3   4  1  2   1.02
--
T/V   N  NB  P  Q   Time
==========================
4     42 4  1  2    1.22
```

The results are separated by `--` in the last grep which can be removed with:

```
$ grep -A2 ^T/V file | grep -v '^--'
```

And with the `====` lines removed:

```
$ grep -A2 ^T/V file | grep -v '^--\|=\+'
```

Answer (score 0):

You got two answers using `awk and grep`, you can also try `sed`:

```
sed -E '/===*/{N;s/.*([0-9]+\.[0-9]*)/\1/g};t;d' file_name
```

Here `/===*/`, will match `===..`, then it will go to next line and find floating point numbers having decimal in between them, and will skip and delete all other lines.

It will print output like:

```
1.02
1.22
```